# Facebook API call for adinterestsuggestion

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am upgrading the api calls for an application that we use inhouse so that it is compliant with the changes starting April 9th. I am looking at the following call for **adinterestsuggestion** and want to know if the syntax is correct. Because it is returning empty dataset and I am not sure what is wrong. I am trying this on the Facebook Graph Api explorer.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterestsuggestion&interest_list=["soda","water"]&limit=&access_token=xyz
I truly appreciate any feedback.

Thanks

Comment: I hope that isn't your real access token?

Comment: It might help if you include the encoded data you are requesting as well, to make it easier to read the request.

Comment: I am just sending type=adinterestsuggestion interest_list=["soda","water"] and limit as empty....what am i doing wrong or am i doing something wrong? i get data back when i make individual adinterest calls for soda and water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API is case sensitive which means your sample call doesn't work because there's no Interest called 'soda' or 'water' when I search the Interest list

There is however one called 'Soda' and one called 'Water' - the `interest_list` parameter you provide needs to match known Interests, which you already know exist from ads you've run before, or from the `adinterest` search type

This returns results for me:
`/search?type=adinterestsuggestion&interest_list=['Soda','Water']`

```
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 6003677833118, 
      "name": "Knorr (brand)", 
      "audience_size": 11707059, 
      "path": [
      ], 
      "description": null
    }, 
    {
      "id": 6003115633342, 
      "name": "Deodorant", 
      "audience_size": 16299816, 
      "path": [
      ], 
      "description": null
    }, 
 ...
```

Comment: you mentioned that you checked the interest list to see if it has contains soda or water. Is there an api call out there that gives a list of all known interests?

Comment: `/search?type=adinterest&q=xxxx` - the adinterestsuggestion search takes known interests and returns other interests which are related / which you may want to target, the adinterest search helps you find interests to start with

Comment: Thanks. I understand the difference. Just wondering if there is an api call out there where in i dont have to specify any suggestion so that i get a list of all possible interest words that facebook supports... :) i guess that will be massive :)